# Why would Linux VM in vSphere ESXi 5.5 show dramatically increased disk i/o latency?

Tags: performance, vmware-esxi, storage, centos6, vmware-vsphere

I'm stumped and I hope someone else will recognize the symptoms of this problem.

Hardware: new Dell T110 II, dual-core Pentium G850 2.9 GHz, onboard SATA controller, one new 500 GB 7200 RPM cabled hard drive inside the box, other drives inside but not mounted yet.  No RAID.  Software: fresh CentOS 6.5 virtual machine under VMware ESXi 5.5.0 (build 1746018) + vSphere Client.  2.5 GB RAM allocated. The disk is how CentOS offered to set it up, namely as a volume inside an LVM Volume Group, except that I skipped having a separate /home and simply have / and /boot.  CentOS is patched up, ESXi patched up, latest VMware tools installed in the VM.  No users on the system, no services running, no files on the disk but the OS installation. I'm interacting with the VM via the VM virtual console in vSphere Client.

Before going further, I wanted to check that I configured things more or less reasonably.  I ran the following command as root in a shell on the VM:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do
  dd if=/dev/zero of=/test.img bs=8k count=256k conv=fdatasync
done
```

I.e., just repeat the dd command 10 times, which results in printing the transfer rate each time. The results are disturbing.  It starts off well:

```
262144+0 records in
262144+0 records out
2147483648 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 20.451 s, 105 MB/s
262144+0 records in
262144+0 records out
2147483648 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 20.4202 s, 105 MB/s
...
```

but after 7-8 of these, it then prints

```
262144+0 records in
262144+0 records out
2147483648 bytes (2.1 GG) copied, 82.9779 s, 25.9 MB/s
262144+0 records in
262144+0 records out
2147483648 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 84.0396 s, 25.6 MB/s
262144+0 records in
262144+0 records out
2147483648 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 103.42 s, 20.8 MB/s
```

If I wait a significant amount of time, say 30-45 minutes, and run it again, it again goes back to 105 MB/s, and after several rounds (sometimes a few, sometimes 10+), it drops to ~20-25 MB/s again.

Based on preliminary search for possible causes, in particular [VMware KB 2011861](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2011861), I changed the Linux i/o scheduler to be "`noop`" instead of the default.  `cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler` shows that it is in effect.  However, I cannot see that it has made any difference in this behavior.

Plotting the disk latency in vSphere's interface, it shows periods of high disk latency hitting 1.2-1.5 *seconds* during the times that `dd` reports the low throughput. (And yes, things get pretty unresponsive while that's happening.)

What could be causing this?

I'm comfortable that it is not due to the disk failing, because I also had configured two other disks as an additional volume in the same system.  At first I thought I did something wrong with that volume, but after commenting the volume out from /etc/fstab and rebooting, and trying the tests on / as shown above, it became clear that the problem is elsewhere.  It is probably an ESXi configuration problem, but I'm not very experienced with ESXi.  It's probably something stupid, but after trying to figure this out for many hours over multiple days, I can't find the problem, so I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

(P.S.: yes, I know this hardware combo won't win any speed awards as a server, and I have reasons for using this low-end hardware and running a single VM, but I think that's besides the point for this question [unless it's actually a hardware problem].)

**ADDENDUM #1**: Reading other answers such as [this one](https://serverfault.com/a/568471/221763) made me try adding `oflag=direct` to `dd`.  However, it makes no difference in the pattern of results: initially the numbers are higher for many rounds, then they drop to 20-25 MB/s.  (The initial absolute numbers are in the 50 MB/s range.)

**ADDENDUM #2**: Adding `sync ; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` into the loop does not make a difference at all.

**ADDENDUM #3**: To take out further variables, I now run `dd` such that the file it creates is larger than the amount of RAM on the system.  The new command is `dd if=/dev/zero of=/test.img bs=16k count=256k conv=fdatasync oflag=direct`.  Initial throughput numbers with this version of the command are ~50 MB/s.  They drop to 20-25 MB/s when things go south.

**ADDENDUM #4**: Here is the output of `iostat -d -m -x 1` running in another terminal window while performance is "good" and then again when it's "bad".  (While this is going on, I'm running `dd if=/dev/zero of=/test.img bs=16k count=256k conv=fdatasync oflag=direct`.) First, when things are "good", it shows this:

[image]

When things go "bad", `iostat -d -m -x 1` shows this:

[image]

**ADDENDUM #5**: At the suggestion of @ewwhite, I tried using `tuned` with different profiles and also tried `iozone`. In this addendum, I report the results of experimenting with whether different `tuned` profiles had any effect on the `dd` behavior described above. I tried changing the profile to `virtual-guest`, `latency-performance` and `throughput-performance`,  keeping everything else the same, rebooting after each change, and then each time running `dd if=/dev/zero of=/test.img bs=16k count=256k conv=fdatasync oflag=direct`. It did not affect the behavior: just as before, things start off fine and many repeated runs of `dd` show the same performance, but then at some point after 10-40 runs, performance drops by half.  Next, I used `iozone`. Those results are more extensive, so I’m putting them in as addendum #6 below.

**ADDENDUM #6**: At the suggestion of @ewwhite, I installed and used `iozone` to test performance. I ran it under different `tuned` profiles, and used a very large maximum file size (4G) parameter to `iozone`. (The VM has 2.5 GB of RAM allocated, and the host has 4 GB total.) These test runs took quite some time. FWIW, the raw data files are available at the links below. In all cases, the command used to produce the files was `iozone -g 4G -Rab filename`.

- Profile `latency-performance`:

  - raw results: http://cl.ly/0o043W442W2r
  - Excel (OSX version) spreadsheet with plots: http://cl.ly/2M3r0U2z3b22
- Profile `enterprise-storage`:

  - raw results: http://cl.ly/333U002p2R1n
  - Excel (OSX version) spreadsheet with plots: http://cl.ly/3j0T2B1l0P46

The following is my summary.

In some cases I rebooted after a previous run, in other cases I didn’t, and simply ran `iozone` again after changing the profile with `tuned`. This did not seem to make an obvious difference to the overall results.

Different `tuned` profiles did not seem (to my admittedly inexpert eyes) to affect the *broad* behavior reported by `iozone`, though the profiles did affect certain details. First, unsurprisingly, some profiles changed the threshold at which performance dropped off for writing very large files: plotting the `iozone` results, you can see a sheer cliff at 0.5 GB for profile `latency-performance` but this drop manifests itself at 1 GB under profile `enterprise-storage`.  Second, although all profiles exhibit weird variability for combinations of small file sizes and small record sizes, the precise pattern of variability differed between profiles. In other words, in the plots shown below, the craggy pattern in the left side exists for all profiles but the locations of the pits and their depths are different in the different profiles. (However, I did not repeat runs of the same profiles to see if the pattern of variability changes noticeably between runs of `iozone` under the same profile, so it is *possible* that what looks like differences between profiles is really just random variability.)

The following are surface plots of the different `iozone` tests for the `tuned` profile of `latency-performance`. The descriptions of the tests are copied from the documentation for `iozone`.

Read test: *This test measures the performance of reading an existing file.*

[image]

Write test: *This test measures the performance of writing a new file.*

[image]

Random read: *This test measures the performance of reading a file with accesses being made to
random locations within the file.*

[image]

Random write: *This test measures the performance of writing a file with accesses being made to random locations within the file.*

[image]

Fread: *This test measures the performance of reading a file using the library function fread(). This is a library routine that performs buffered & blocked read operations. The buffer is within the user’s address space. If an application were to read in very small size transfers then the buffered & blocked I/O functionality of fread() can enhance the performance of the application by reducing the number of actual operating system calls and increasing the size of the transfers when operating system calls are made.*

[image]

Fwrite: *This test measures the performance of writing a file using the library function fwrite(). This is a library routine that performs buffered write operations. The buffer is within the user’s address space. If an application were to write in very small size transfers then the buffered & blocked I/O functionality of fwrite() can enhance the performance of the application by reducing the number of actual operating system calls and increasing the size of the transfers when operating system calls are made. This test is writing a new file so again the overhead of the metadata is included in the measurement.*

[image]

Finally, during the time that `iozone` was doing its thing, I also examined the performance graphs for the VM in vSphere 5’s client interface. I switched back and forth between the real-time plots of the virtual disk and the datastore. The available plotting parameters for the datastore were greater than for the virtual disk, and the datastore performance plots seemed to mirror what the disk and virtual disk plots were doing, so here I enclose only a snapshot of the datastore graph taken after `iozone` finished (under `tuned` profile `latency-performance`).  The colors are a little bit hard to read, but what is perhaps most notable are the sharp vertical spikes in *read* latency (e.g., at 4:25, then again slightly after 4:30, and again between 4:50-4:55).  Note: the plot is unreadable when embedded here, so I've also uploaded it to http://cl.ly/image/0w2m1z2T1z2b

[image: vSphere real-time plot of VM]

I must admit, I don’t know what to make of all this.  I especially don’t understand the weird pothole profiles in the small record/small file size regions of the `iozone` plots.

Comment: Assuming that you have been using high disk utilization in terms of IOPS for a long period of time, then you are likely experiencing disk saturation at some level (either at the os disk write queue level or more likely at the hard disk level) where you have more requests than your disk can handle at the moment. I am not experienced enough to tell you how to determine whether you are experiencing disk saturation but I think it might be a point of investigation for you.

Comment: @JasonZhu It's a good question. I've been assuming that because the system is doing nothing else, and I'm merely running the same command repeatedly, the level of disk usage would be roughly constant.  Yet, it takes a long time before the behavior manifests itself despite this.  I did run `iostat` and it showed ~90% utilization both before and after. But I'm not an expert in judging these things – maybe saturation is happening somewhere. I'm updating my question to show `iostat` output in case it's useful.

Comment: Is there any chance this is due to ESX disk caching? Is the disk you're testing optimized for performance or safety? Also, if it's optimized for performance, can you look at the ESX cache utilization while you're testing? This write IO change in throughput looks like writes hitting a cache, and then slowing to the destage speed when it fills up.

Comment: Could that have anything to do with you RAID controller cache? High IOPS/throughput until it's full and then you fall back to raw HDD performance? Just guessing...

Comment: @MarioLenz As I mentioned in the description, this has no RAID.

Comment: @Basil What is a good way to look at the cache utilization? I've looked through all the vsphere performance graphs, but none seem to be exactly about cache utilization.

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. I normally deal with it at a storage controller level, but this is on an internal disk.

Answer (score 2):

Can you give the exact ESXi build number? Please try tests again with a purpose-built disk performance analysis tool like [**fio**](http://freecode.com/projects/fio) or [**iozone**](http://www.iozone.org) to get a real baseline. Using `dd` is not really productive for this.

In general, the default I/O scheduler in EL6 isn't that great. You should be looking at shifting to the deadline or noop I/O elevators, or better yet, installing the [**tuned framework**](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/tuned-adm.html).

Try: `yum install tuned tuned-utils` and `tuned-adm profile virtual-guest`, then test again.

Comment: Argh, I neglected to mention that I did actually change the scheduler to noop. I'll edit my question to say that. As for build number, it's 1746018. (I did include that in the 2nd paragraph, but I see something happened and it was truncated -- must have been an editing accident. I'll fix that too.) I'll look into the tuned framework and the other tools. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I tried `tuned`, using profile `virtual-guest` and keeping everything else the same (proper experimental technique -- avoid changing more than one variable).  It did not affect the behavior: just as before, things start off fine, but after many repeated runs (10-30) of `dd if=/dev/zero of=/test.img bs=16k count=256k conv=fdatasync oflag=direct`, performance drops by half.  I also tried profile `latency-performance` -- same result. I'm currently trying `throughput-performance`.

Comment: Can you try something that doesn't involve `dd` runs? Perhaps the `fio` or `iozone` mentioned earlier?

Comment: I will. But first, it made sense to repeat the same test, to see if the behavior changed.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and noticed a very slow drive performance within virtual machines. I'm using ESXi 5.5 on a Seagate ST33000650NS.

By following [this](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003469) kb article I changed `Disk.DiskMaxIOSize` to my disks block size. In my case `4096`.

VMware note on this is very nice, since you can just test it.

> Note: You can make this change without rebooting the ESX/ESXi host or without putting the ESX/ESXi host in maintenance mode.

I know this question is very old, but mhucka put so much energy and information in his post, that I had to answer.

**Edit#1:** After using 4096 for a day, I switched back to the old value `32767`. Testing the IO and everything still seems to be stable.  My guess is that running a ESXi on a normal HDD with `Disk.DiskMaxIOSize` set to `32767` will work fine for some hours or maybe days. Maybe it takes some load from the VMs to gradually reduce the performance.

I try to investigate and come back later...

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. It is useful to know about changing the disk block size. I regret I can't test it because I no longer have this configuration (I finally ditched it and went with CentOS on bare metal), but if ever I try something like this again, you can be sure I'll be looking into this.

Comment: I was trying to figure out high latency times on my esxi 6.5 on ProLiant 380 Gen9 machine. `Disk.DiskMaxIOSize` did the trick for me. I was researching and measuring for 2 weeks now. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out where in your storage stack the high latencies are caused:

[image]

source: [Troubleshooting Storage Performance in vSphere – Part 1 – The Basics](http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2012/05/troubleshooting-storage-performance-in-vsphere-part-1-the-basics.html)